Spark Read Format to handle delimiter, escape and multiple quotes in a column
I am trying to read a source file which has a column called Description. The delimiter is ','. This is column can have special character, string, numbers.
The source data is like:



Id
Description
No
Amount




1
AbcQ AB2480 BCD abcdefgh 24" ABC,abcdefgh abcde
null
120


2
\
null
320



This data is present in gzip format. I am reading this in spark.
I want the description to be as is. Even if they can't be as is, I don't want them to right shift or left shift so it does not disturb the 'Amount' column.
I am reading it with code:
inputFileDf1 = (spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("quote",'"')
    .option("multiLine","true")
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
    .option("compression", "gzip")
    .load(path_dm))

Now this code works fine for 1st row ( Id = 1), but for 2nd row I get "," in description column instead of \. Lets say there is another column after amount, the value left shifts and gives incorrect results. 320 which was the amount is now coming in No and so on and now the amount column is messed up for this row.



Id
Description
No
Amount




1
AbcQ AB2480 BCD abcdefgh 24" ABC,abcdefgh abcde
null
120


2
","
320
45



To fix the second row, I use
inputFileDf1 = (spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("quote",'"')
    .option("escape","")
    .option("multiLine","true")
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
    .option("compression", "gzip")
    .load(path_dm))

This fixes the second row but disturbs the first row.



Id
Description
No
Amount




1
"AbcQ AB2480 BCD abcdefgh 24" ABC
abcdefgh abcde"
null


2
\
null
320



Now with this, second row is right but column are shifted for the first row because there was a , present and without escape it splits the description into next column and the amount column is messed up for this row.
Some Constraints:

I cannot change the source file - One way would be to change and replace \ character in source file itself but I cannot do that, I only want to do it while reading

I cannot change the delimiter at this point.


What is the best way to resolve this?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

In the question, you share the source data as a table format. Could you provide a sample of what the source data looks like in the CSV format?

Its actually ingested and compressed in gzip so I cannot directly open the file and since I work on a jumpbox certain tools to unzip are not allowed so I cannot see the ingested file directly. I have mentioned how it looks like in the source table in the description.

@Priyam Have you tried escaping the backslash?

@VikasSharma - Yes I tried, it doesn't work somehow.
inputFileDf1 = (spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("quote",'"')
    .option("escape","\\")
    .option("multiLine","true")
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
    .option("compression", "gzip")
    .load(path_dm))

This, right? It doesn't work. for second row it give ',' in Description field

Is there any way to view a more raw format using spark.read.text(path_dm).option("compression", "gzip")?
Im thinking about different options to split this file since it doesn't seem fit the CSV file format expectations. Understanding how it looks in a more raw format, can help with designing work-arounds to get the format of your input file into a dataframe.
